# Send reset password link to user from custom lost password form

Tags: login, buddypress, password

I've been struggling searching through a bunch of tutorials with no luck. I have a custom login page and am just replacing the login form with the forgot password form on click. My issue is how to get the form to send the user a reset password link if the correct username or email is entered and return an error if not. I'm trying to do this from a plugin I'm making to handle the login. Here's my simple form. How do I make this work?

```
  <form id="wp_pass_reset" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="email-field" name="user_input" value="Username or Email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit" value="Reset" />
  </form>
```

Comment: So anyone could reset anyone's password?

Comment: lol doh Im gonna edit this

Comment: This is right article for you. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/wordpress-custom-forgot-password-page/

Comment: I using olympus theme on wordpress. the lost password url redirecrecting to homapage url. here is the code that used for reset password section:
```php
<?php $lostpswd = apply_filters( 'yz_lostpassword_url', wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $lostpswd ); ?>" class="forgot"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Forgot my Password', 'crum-ext-sign-form' ); ?>
</a>
``` what I should to do?

Comment: First you'll need to workout whether wp_lostpassword_url() is returning the wrong URL, or whether it's the yz_lostpassword_url filter that's returning the wrong URL. e.g. just set `$lostpswd  = wp_lostpassword_url();` and see what happens?

Comment: However you've posted this as an answer to an existing question when it's really a new question. If you need more help, can you ask this as a new question instead please? Do link back to this question if it's useful for context. Thanks!

Comment: @zahra you should ask new questions as new questions, don't post them as solutions to other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you would first set the redirect URL either to nothing: `$redirect='';` or the fully qualified URL of the page you want your user to land on after successfully changing their password.  For  http://example.com/mypage/ you would use: `$redirect=site_url( '/mypage/ ' );`

Then your form would be:

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform" action="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Username or E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10"></label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $redirect ?>">
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Get New Password" tabindex="100"></p>
</form>
```

Note: This code is untested.  Let me know what happens in the comments if something doesn't work.

**Update**

As noted in the comments, if you have a filter on login_url `wp_lostpassword_url()` will point to your custom page.  To temporarily restore the default login_url, remove the filter right before the form code:

```
remove_filter( 'login_url', 'your_filter_function' );
```

and add it back right after the form code:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'your_filter_function' );
```

Comment: Is this sending a link with a unique key to the email entered if it's a valid email address of a user? I'm trying to replicate the default method wordpress uses only the link they get sent is pointed to my reset password template and not wordpress's.

Comment: Have you filtered the login_url to point to your reset template?  If so, you'll have to capture the original login_url value in your filter so you can use it instead of the call to wp_lostpassword_url()

Comment: or alternately remove your filter before the form code, and restore it afterwards.  Probably easier that way.