# Alter the reset password link

Tags: plugins, reset, password

after clicking on the reset password option in WP, we're getting this link

```
wp-login.php?action=rp&key=[theKey]&login=testing>
```

instead of getting this can we alter it to something link to out custom page?

Comment: Did you search this stack? Have you seen [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64156/send-reset-password-link-to-user-from-custom-lost-password-form), for instance? If so, please elaborate on how the answer does not apply to your situation. What have you tried so far? Giving a bit more information on what is you want to *exactly* do will certainly increase the likelihood of a quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'lostpass_url_fix');
function lostpass_url_fix( $link ){
    return 'http://example.com';
}
```

Just replace the example.com with any url you want